# Speed up apply function with data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with population like below -

```
   RegionName     State  2000-01  2000-02  2000-03  2000-04 ...  2016-10  2016-11  2016-12
0  New York        NY      204      300      300      124    ...    456     566        344 
1  Mountain View   CA      204      300      300      124    ...    456     566        344
```

There are nearly `~10K rows` in the dataset. For this dataset, I want to add columns for average population for each quarter of years from `2000 to 2016`.

I wrote a function to `apply` to the dataframe as below -

```
import numpy as np
def quarterize(row):
   quarter_to_months_map = {
      'q1' : ['01', '02', '03'],
      'q2' : ['04', '05', '06'],
      'q3' : ['07', '08', '09'],
      'q4' : ['10', '11', '12']
   }
   for year in range(2000, 2017):
      year = '{}'.format(year)
      for quarter in quarter_to_months_map.keys():
          values = []
          for month in quarter_to_months_map[quarter]:
             values.append(row['{}-{}'.format(year, month)])
          row['{}{}'.format(year, quarter)] = np.nanmean(values)
      return row

df = df.apply(quarterize, axis = 1)
```

This works fine but smaller datasets but the `~10K` dataset, this would take `~10 min`. Is there a way to make this more efficient and much faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Never operate on rows, operate on columns instead.

Something along the lines of:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([[random.randint(150, 300) for x in range(12 * 10)] for _ in range(1000)],
                 columns=['{}-{:02d}'.format(year, month) for month in range(1,13) for year in range(2000, 2010)])

quarter_to_months_map = {
      'q1' : ['01', '02', '03'],
      'q2' : ['04', '05', '06'],
      'q3' : ['07', '08', '09'],
      'q4' : ['10', '11', '12']
   }

for year in range(2000, 2010):
    for quarter, months in quarter_to_months_map.items():
        months = ['{}-{}'.format(year, month) for month in months]
        df['{}{}'.format(year, quarter)] = df[months].mean(axis=1)
```